# List item inside #footer text not going to center

Tags: css, xhtml

I want to keep list item in the center of `#footer` `div` always. Footer is flexible.

I'm using current code but it's not making list item in center.

```
#footer {overflow:hidden;text-align:center}
#footer ul {margin:0 auto}
#footer li {float:left;padding:10px;text-align:center}
```

HTML

```
<div id="footer">
  <ul>
    <li>item1</li> 
    <li>item2</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I am assuming your question is: How can I center the list item within the footer? My question is - can you post your footer and list item markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ul {text-align:center;}
li {display:inline;padding:10px;}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. but it needs to specify height on `footer` or on `ul`